# Using family sharing, can a child account do in-app purchases without approval?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, in-app-purchase

I recently added my son to our "iTunes family"; I have set his Apple ID up as a child account and have checked the "Ask to Buy: require approval from parent for all purchases ..." checkbox.

Yet today I received an app store invoice for an in-app purchase my son made in one of the games he plays. Do in-app purchases not fall under the "require approval from parent" rule?

(I know that I can prevent in-app purchases by configuring "Restrictions" on his iPad, but that is not the point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app purchases do fall under the same rule, however if your Apple ID is signed into, say a family computer, he could approve it himself on that device.

Comment: that should not be the case, but I'll check later and update the comment accordingly

Comment: after checking I can confirm that in-app purchases from a "child" family member do indeed require a parent's approval. I just recently "converted" my son's Apple ID from adult to child, so I assume that the purchase was made while the ID was still an adult and it just took a few days for the invoice to arrive.